# Geth JSON keys VS MEW JSON keys

Tags: go-ethereum, keystore

The format of JSON keystores created by the Go-Ethereum Geth executable are slightly different format than the JSON keys created on the MyEtherWallet website. Can anyone explain the differences? I have found that the Geth executable unlocks the MEW format much faster in an embedded/low resource environment. One of the things I noticed was the "n" value in kdfparams is much lower in MEW keys than GO-Ether Geth key format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format used for this wallets allows choosing different algorithms, commonly used are scrypt and PBKDF2.

Likely your wallet use scrypt, in that case "n" controls how much temporary memory will be used. A larger "n" means it will take longer to open your wallet, but it also means it will be more secure.

Usually programs choose "n" such that opening a wallet is not very noticeable to users. Geth being a compiled language can choose a large value for "n", but MEW being interpreted javascript has to choose a smaller value for "n".

Comment: Yea I found posts about Scrypt parameters. I was having very slow unlock times on embedded devices, 10-15 minutes. So I edited the beginning of the account keystore_passphrase.go file. Lowered the N value and then recompile Geth. I am running the executable on embedded linux, OpenWrt. The RAM is only 64MB with 1GB swap.